# Why does one of my objects disappear when I render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm new to Blender and I finished one scene. Everything is good when I look at the scene in the object mode or rendered preview, but when I actually render the scene, my doughnuts disappear and the icing starts looking very sharp and edgy. Please, look at the attached images.
Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Better upload the file, try [this](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Please read through the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up that list some of the possible causes for an object not to render.

Answer (score 6):

My assumption is that it is hidden from the render. Go to the *outliner* and make sure that both the eye and camera aren't grayed out.

[image]

Otherwise make sure that all of the following optios are checked (make sure object is selected).
[image]

**Edit**

Icing:

In the modifier tab make sure render of the subdivision-surface is same as view.:

[image]

Comment: Another possibility can be scene render layers. The sharp edges can be due to the two settings in the SS modifier: one for preview and one for rendering

Comment: I guess, but I watched the series (Blender Guru) which this scene is based on, and it doesn't touch render layers. I doubt a beginner would use more intermediate tools such as render layers. But yes it could be the render layers.

Comment: Yes, so many possibilities, That's why I've been asking for the exact problematic file, especiallly for a what-is-wrong-with-my-scene question like this.

Comment: A file would be helpful because of what you said