# My Donut sprinkles not showing in rendering my blender?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

My Donut sprinkles not showing in rendering my blender version v2.79  i m begginer i need help please My project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wX9mngWBoK5XGccuJMY8Iz3b0koTypxy/view?usp=sharing

[image: see this :(]

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78780/why-does-one-of-my-objects-disappear-when-i-render

Comment: Welcome to blender.stackexchange.com. You have set the Particle-System > Children > Simple. Change this option to "None" then it will work :)

Comment: is the eye/camera on in part particles meun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the Particle-System > Children > **Simple**:
[image]

Change this option to **None**:

[image]

But if you also want to use **Children** particles then adjust the **Size** and to see them in the viewport, set **Display > 0** or **Display = Render**,

[image]

Comment: so why didn't it work with Simple?

Comment: @moonboots I have updated my answer. Actually, the size of children particles was very small.

Comment: Oh ok thanks  ;)

Comment: Thank u so so much you saved my 2 months of hardwork